# Enacting a POST request to URL in Symfony using CURL

Tags: php, symfony, post, curl

I have a controller in symfony2 that is a post request.

```
$current_hardware_version = $request->request->get('hardware_version');
```

I send a curl request in my terminal simulating a call to this

```
curl --data "hardware_version = 10" http://localhost/app_dev.php/api/hardware_version/00-11-22-33-44-55
```

yet, I reference the variable in the function and nothing is printed out but "function over" which I coded at the end of the action. Am I not passing the post param properly to this url in curl?

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces from the parameter quotes:

```
curl --data "hardware_version=10" http://localhost/app_dev.php/api/hardware_version/00-11-22-33-44-55
```

Comment: I answered it as an answer, so yes.